# Getting FATAL EXCEPTION while drawing image using "ImageView"

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I am getting **FATAL EXCEPTION** while trying to draw image using `ImageView` after taking that image using mobile camera.

exception:

```
06-04 21:11:10.390: D/AndroidRuntime(19857): Shutting down VM
06-04 21:11:10.414: W/dalvikvm(19857): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.nirbhaya/com.example.nirbhaya.MMS}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at com.example.nirbhaya.MMS.onActivityResult(MMS.java:124)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
06-04 21:11:10.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19857):    ... 11 more
```

and code::
    package com.example.nirbhaya;

```
public class MMS extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
public static int count=0;
EditText preLoc,comeby;
Button ok,capture;
String photo;
String dir;

boolean GPS,flag;
String cityName=null; 
String SubThorugh = null;
Intent i;
ImageView iv;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mms);

    preLoc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPreLoc1);
    comeby = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etComing1);
    //ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bOK1);
    capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btnCapture:
        capturePicture();
        break;

    }
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "photo saved as: "+photo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
private void capturePicture() {

    //here,we are making a folder named picFolder to store pics taken by the camera using this application
    final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/"; 
    File newdir = new File(dir); 
    newdir.mkdirs();
 // here,counter will be incremented each time,and the picture taken by camera will be stored as 1.jpg,2.jpg and likewise.
    count++;
    String file = dir+count+".jpg";
    photo = file;
    File newfile = new File(file);
    try {
        newfile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {}       

    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);

}

}
```

After adding below code still i am getting following error

> iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

```
06-04 22:15:46.515: W/dalvikvm(22711): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.nirbhaya/com.example.nirbhaya.MMS}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at com.example.nirbhaya.MMS.onActivityResult(MMS.java:125)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
06-04 22:15:46.546: E/AndroidRuntime(22711):    ... 11 more
06-04 22:15:46.921: D/dalvikvm(22711): GC_CONCURRENT freed 268K, 48% free 2956K/5639K, external 583K/945K, paused 3ms+4ms
```

Comment: Hello, anyone Please help on this event.

Answer (score 2):

`iv` is null. You need to create it from XML or similar.

For example

`iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);`

assuming you have it somewhere in `R.layout.mms`

Comment: Still getting exception and that was added at below

Comment: Which line exactly is line 125 of MMS.java? Something there is null.

Comment: Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");